# MySQL order by other tables row

Tags: mysql, date

I've got those two tables:

Table a:
`--- ID --- Name ---`
Table b:
`--- ID --- ID_of_a --- Date ---`

Now I want to order the rows of `table a` by the `Date` (desc) of `table b` by the newest date.
Example:
`Table a` has rows with ID "1" and "2".
`Table b` has rows like this: {ID, ID_of_a, Date} {1, 1, "2013-06-30"}, {2, 1, "2013-07-01" }, {3, 2, "2013-07-02" }
The correct order of IDs from table a would be: 1 --- 2
Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, a.Name FROM a, b WHERE a.ID=b.ID_of_a ORDER BY b.Date desc
```

But this doesn't work sometimes.

Comment: What doesn't work at times?

Comment: What query do you use that "doesn't work sometimes"

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. I totalle forgot about that. - Edited

Comment: Shouldn't expected order be `2---1` because 2 has the newest date and you want descending sort

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is a 1-1 relationship between the tables:

```
select a.*
from a left outer join
     b
     on a.id = b.id
order by b.date desc
```

If there are multiple rows in `b` for each `a`, then you need a `group by`:

```
select a.*
from a left outer join
     b
     on a.id = b.id
group by a.id
order by max(b.date) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select a.name,a.id from a join (select id_of_a as id_a,max(dt) as max_dt from b group by id_of_a order by max_dt desc) e on e.id_a=a.id
```

Example

```
mysql> select * from a;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from b;
+----+---------+------------+
| id | id_of_a | dt         |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2013-06-20 |
|  2 |       2 | 2013-07-01 |
|  3 |       1 | 2013-07-02 |
+----+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select a.name,a.id from a join (select id_of_a as id_a,max(dt) as max_dt from b group by id_of_a order by max_dt desc) e on e.id_a=a.id;
+------+----+
| name | id |
+------+----+
| a    |  1 |
| b    |  2 |
+------+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Basically you first select the maximum date for each `id_of_a` and then join it to `a`

I think it can be re-written to run more efficiently